# Older sci fi book about a young woman who goes on a planet-hopping tour and ends up bonding with a living spaceship

Tags: story-identification, books

This book or trilogy/series I'm trying to remember is about a young adult girl who decides to go on a kind of planet hopping rumspringa, instead of pursuing a job or further schooling. The society she lives in provides a type of free hostel for those without means, and these hostels provide generic clothing, and tasteless but nutritious food bars.

She ends up on a type of living spacecraft, and "bonding" with it, (symbiotically as its kind of captain), and eventually this becomes her "purpose".

I read this over 30 years ago and can't remember the name(s), or author.

Comment: Welcome to Science Fiction & Fantasy! You've provided some good details for your query, but please review the answers to [How to ask a good story-ID question?](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/1234) and see if you are able to add any additional details that might help people find your story. You can directly [edit] your question to add anything else you might remember.

Comment: _[The Ship Who Sang](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Ship_Who_Sang)_ by Anne McCaffrey is sort-of like this, but the genders are reversed.

Comment: @Spencer -- *The Ship Who Sang* was my first thought, but except for "living spaceship", the details don't match.  No actual symbiotic bonding, no planet hopping spree, no hostels.  The "brawns" were trained for that position.

Comment: I also thought of _[Child of Fortune](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Child_of_Fortune)_ (1985) by Norman Spinrad. But I don't think there was any symbiotic bonding with a ship there, either. Just with an enormous tree.

Comment: Reminds me a bit of [Surface Detail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Detail) by Iain M. Banks, except there the girl is a slave and the ships (plural) who help her and bond with her are only really introduced later in the piece.

Comment: Thanks all, turns out I was thinking about 2 different books: The Void Captain's Tale and Child of Fortune.  It's been so long since I read either of them I guess I "mashed" them together - lol. I appreciate your help with reminding me 

Comment: @D.LynnShockley You should post this as an answer, and explain which bits come from which book.